# What is the highest possible attack rating in Dark Souls?

Tags: dark-souls

What's the highest possible attack rating for a melee weapon in dark souls?

Assuming max stats and using any enchantment on any weapon. Right now I am getting 706 rating with the crystal demon's greataxe +5.

Comment: This is too broad. There are too many weapons and too many stat combinations to determine this.

Comment: @Ben Well, there should one simple  answer, so... not "too broad" IMO.

Comment: @user2656801 Just to clarify : do you mean pure Physical Damage, or total AR, including elements ?

Comment: The highest possible will be to be level 999, using best stat scaled weapon, and max the stat(s).  It isn't practical, but it is "max".

Comment: It's also utterly irrelevant, as the effort required to achieve it is astronomical.

Comment: @Ben That's absolutely true. And that is why it hasn't been answered. Everytime someone pops the question, the answer is 'oh it's too broad, or it's not specific enough', and the question is swept under the rug. I poped this question for ds2 and it got 10k views without a real reply. People want the answer. And everyone is too lazy to look at the code and find out. I think the real way to solve it would be to import all weapons in the game into like a spreadsheet with formulas for scaling and see what happens.

Comment: @user2656801 If you feel like this is answerable, go ahead and answer it yourself, by all means. The main problem is that getting the answer is going to be *far* too much work for a bit of online credit (as Frank already suggested), and will likely also ruin the fun of the game.

Comment: @user2656801 Additionally, you other question was answered to the best of the ability that anyone might have been willing to provide, and even then, the discussion still went in the direction that there is just too many outside factors.

Comment: @Ben If could answer it himself, he wouldn't need to ask the question... and I've never seen a rule saying "no hard-to-answer questions", so my vote is to keep this open.

Comment: @BlueRaja, Not necessarily, if he was able to answer it I'd say his rep would likely explode. And there's no harm in asking and answering a question for the sake of others (like he pointed out beforehand, his other similar question is currently sitting at ~40k views), but yes, there's no rule against it.

Comment: @Frank Your standards for "astronomical" are low... look up the sidequests for the best limit breaks and summons in FF7

Comment: @LucasLeblanc: To reach level 999, you need 1 695 000 000 souls. The highest-scored boss, Gwyn Lord of Cinder on NG+6 yields 175,000 souls. You'd need to finish this (extremely hard) battle 9,686 times just for the level-up. And that is not accounting for the items. Simply put, unlike FF7, DS has exponential progression of requirements and really distant caps that really makes the numbers required to approach them astronomical.

Comment: Actually, this is for dark souls one.  I don't think you get bonfire ascetic options like DS2, so the grind will be very, very significant... You either find online games for this super old game, or you ultra grind weenies.

Comment: You can't reach level 999, max level is 715 for most classes. Knight max level is 711. level 715 takes 8,949,476 souls. You can get up to 700k souls per hour farming tomb of the giants. You can get max level in ds in 13 hours of farming. That's not that much when people spend thousands of hours grinding games like runescape.

Comment: in fact. you can't get level 999 in any souls games... max level in ds2 is 836? or something like that.

Comment: @user2656801 I ask again. Do you want the whole actual rating, including element, or the pure physical damage ?

Comment: 'Greatsword of Artorias' has stat scaling with all 4 attributes, so it is a likely candidate for highest AR with a max stat char.

Comment: http://www.gamefaqs.com/xbox360/608635-dark-souls/answers/298657-what-is-the-most-powerful-weapon-in-the-game  this discussion says the answer is 'enchanted great club'.

Comment: @Ealhad entire rating.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Demon's Greataxe](http://darksouls.wikia.com/wiki/Demon%27s_Greataxe) has the highest potential raw damage, due to nice base attack rating and S-scaling in Strength. A **Crystal Demon's Greataxe +5** wielded with 99 Strength has 767 attack rating.
<sup>*Note : Two-handing doesn't boost damage at 99 Strength*</sup>

This weapon can be enchanted.

The best weapon augmentation is [**Darkmoon Blade**](http://darksouls.wikia.com/wiki/Darkmoon_Blade) ; when rank 3 in the [Blade of the Darkmoon](http://darksouls.wikia.com/wiki/Blade_of_the_Darkmoon) covenant, (magic) damage increase is 2.1x of the magic adjust of the equipped talisman.

The best talisman is the [**Darkmoon Talisman**](http://darksouls.wikia.com/wiki/Darkmoon_Talisman). With 99 Faith, it has 240 magic adjust, resulting in 504 magic damage for Darkmoon Blade.

### Maximum attack rating in Dark Souls : 1271, with 99 Strength and Faith, Crystal Demon's Greataxe +5, Darkmoon Talisman, and Darkmoon Blade.

Starting with the Cleric class, this is SL174, long but not that hard to achieve. No ring nor equipment piece can boost this rating.

Here is the build on [Mugenmonkey](https://www.mugenmonkey.com/darksouls/?b=Y2xlcmljLDExLDExLDksOTksOCwxMSw4LDk5LDAsNTYsMCwwLDAsMCwwLDEyOSw2NCwwLDAsbm9ybWFsLGNyeXN0YWwsbm9ybWFsLG5vcm1hbCwwLDYxLDAsMCwwLDAsMCwwLDAsMCwwLDAsMCwzLHdvb2Rlbix3b29kZW4sd29vZGVuLHdvb2RlbiwxLDAsMCwxLDI3LDAsMCww).

Praise the Sun !

Comment: Good job. I got 1272 attack rating in game. You are right this is the highest attack rating in the game.

Answer (score 0):

The strongest unbuffed weapon, with 99 all stats & ignoring stuff like RTSR & Power Within, is an Enchanted Demon Great Machete with 812 AR. Enchanted Demon's Greathammer has an AR of 811, & the axe has an AR of 810 
I'm unsure what the exact number of a 99 int Tin Crystalization Catalyst Crystal Magic Weapon buff is, but tumblebuffing that onto the Great Machete would give you the highest AR in the game 
Without using glitches, the highest AR is a CMW TCC buffed Crystal Demon's Greataxe, with a base AR of 767
But in terms of what would do the most damage, a tumblebuffed CMW Moonlight Greatsword is most effective

Answer (score -1):

A rating closer to the actual maximum would be the **2132 AR** achievable by tumblebuffing a +5 Grant with Crystal Magic Weapon using a Tin Crystallization Catalyst + RTSR + Power within's 40% (1523 is the total displayed amount, as PW's AR increase isn't shown in menu). Stats were 50 STR, 50 INT and 50 FAI, so you could expect even more.

I'll do some testing later today with an Enhanced Great club +5 with Darkmoon blade +3 + Darkmoon talisman and Crystal Magic weapon + Tin Crystallization Catalyst.

Answer (score -1):

With glitches and spells the highest is +5 enchanted great club with 99 strength And Int and faith (faith is for later), to increase it use powerwithin and RTSR and tumble buff the weapon and caster swap the caster from talisman to tin crystallisation catalyst and use the spell dark moon blade at max rank with the blade of the dark moons and have a friend use the trident dance you should reach well over 2.5k (I forgot the actual number)

**Now to avoided glitches** use the crystal demons greataxe and do the steps before just don’t tumble buff/caster swap and the weapon buff should be Darkmoon Blade with the darkmoon talisman

Comment: From a suggested edit: "TCC and Crystal magic weapon + max level dragon torso stone roar does slightly more damage than DMB and DMC buff, tested 1889 with DMB+3+base level DTS 1941 with CMW+DTSmax level, tested with 99 str 99 faith 99 int"